Rails Turbolinks not working when promoting to production on Heroku
I have the following setup:
Rails 7 app, Turbolinks (loading/compiling via sprockets)

local dev environment -> localhost
staging on Heroku -> appstaging.herokuapp.com
production on Heroku (1st language) -> appprod1.herokuapp.com + realdomain.com
production on Heroku (2nd language) -> appprod2.herokuapp.com + realdomain.es

realdomain.com and realdomain.es are accessable via Cloudflare (if this is somehow relevant)
Turbolinks works fine on local, staging and production when accessing via appprod1/2.herokuapp.com and realdomain.es
However, on realdomain.com Turbolinks is not working (also tried different clients/devices). The JS code is included and loaded in application.js as expected (I can see it in the browser's dev-tools). But when I click a link it is loaded via http instead of xhr. And the turbolinks:load event is not fired, too.
Any other JS is running - only Turbolinks is on strike.
It seems that the problem relates to the specific domain (i.e. realdomain.com) because all other instances and domains work great. But I have no technical explanation for that!?
I already purged the cache at Heroku without any success.
Any ideas what else to try or fix?

After some more hours of research I finally found this post:
turbolinks:load event works on local machine not on Heroku
I had to turn off Rocket Loader, a JS "optimization tool" by Cloudflare. This tool somehow destroys Turbolinks' logic - WTF! I would never have figured that out myself!
There is another link in the post that explains how to turn off Rocket Loader. Now Turbolinks does his job without any hiccups...
Maybe this answer will help someone else too (knowing that Rails 7 and Turbolinks is not the most common combination, though).
